# Unknown error while builing app in Device

Tags: iphone

I am running an application in Device and i get this eroor 
 `Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).`
but i build the same app in stimulator and it works perfect.
i deleted the app from the device,and restart it.
i swithoff the iphone.
i clered the cashe from the xcode.
try a new build
but again this eroor comes while building it in Device.
please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Will your app run on the 4.3 simulator or just the 5.0 simulator?

Answer (score 0):

what is your device version? I think this may your problem.

Just change your  "deployment target" in project preferences.